# How to catch 403 response inside graphql api call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, graphql

I have a server that does the rendering of the component and returns an HTML when the request is made while rendering the server does a graphql call for a particular component which sometimes returns a 403 response.

Code:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: 'https://url/graphql',
    fetch,
    headers: {
      'csrf-tokens': tokens,
      Referer: header_referer,
    },
  }),
  queryDeduplication: false
)}

export const getProperties = async () => {
  try {
    await client
      .query({query, variables})
      .then((response) => {
         const data = response.data.properties;
         if(response.error) {
           throw new Error("Error encountered");
         }
       }
      .catch((error) => {
         console.log("gettProperites error")
      })
   } catch (err) {
       console.log("Execution failed")
   }
}
```

I'm making a graphql call inside the getProperties function and whenever I get a 403 error my pod crashes. I have wrapped the call inside try-catch block and added an additional if condition inside .then() to check for any error inside the response. Still, the 403 response is not caught and crashes the pod.

The above code is the overall structure of the code that I'm running, I have removed a few details that were not required to keep it small.

Comment: Do you catch and throw error when you encounter 403 from your server?

Answer (score 0):

Try interceptors.
I can just tell for vue, but I think in react it's quite similar:

```
const link = createUploadLink({ uri: '/graphql' });

const errors = onError(({ networkError }) => {
    if (networkError.statusCode === 403) {
      // do something with 403 response code like:
      router.push('/403');
    }
    else {
      // do something with any other error response code
    }
  })

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link:  errors.concat(link),
  ...
})
```